# Optimal Directed Graph with Maximum Number of Interactions

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-optimization

**Definitions:**

- The number of *interactions* of a directed graph $(V,E)$, denoted by $\operatorname{inter}(V,E)$ is defined by
  $$
  \operatorname{inter}(V,E) = \sum_{e,f\in V} I_{\gamma{[e,f]}},
  $$
  where $I_{\gamma[e,f]}=1$ if there exists a path in $(V,E)$ beginning at $e$ and ending at $f$, and takes value $0$ otherwise.
- We say that two elements $e,f\in V$ are connected if there is a path beginning at $e$ and ending at $f$; i.e.: $I_{[e,f]}=1$.

---

**Question:**

Let $V_1,V_2$ be non-empty finite sets of the same cardinalty and $N\geq |V|$ be a fixed positive integer.  If we're allowed to add nodes to $V_1\cup V_2$ (so suppose $V_1\cup V_2$ is contained in a very large but finite set $V$) how can we construct the graph $(V^{\star},E^{\star})$ with:

1. Exactly N edges,
2. Every member of $V_1$ is connected to some member of $V_2$,
3. There is no path from $V_2$ to $V_1$,
4. If a graph $(V,E)$ satisfies $1-3$ then
   $$
   \operatorname{inter}(V,E) \leq \operatorname{inter}(V^{\star},E^{\star})
   .
   $$

Comment: Apparently, $e$ and $f$ are nodes, so $E$ is a node set.  Is $V$ an edge set?  Normally, the symbols $V$ and $E$ have the reverse meanings.

Comment: Oh I didn't know.  I fixed this.  But yes

Comment: $V$ for vertex, and $E$ for edge.  Also sometimes $N$ for node, and $A$ for arc.

Comment: If you are allowed to modify $V_1$ and $V_2$, it is better to give the new ones different names, like $V_1^*$ and $V_2^*$.  Do you require $|V_1^*|=|V_2^*|$?  What is the relationship between $E$ and $E^*$?

Comment: Oh no we cannot modify $V_1$ and $V_2$ but only $V$.  The goal is to place N edges between (possibly more vertices) connecting $V_1$ to $V_2$.  So A priori there is no relationship between $E$ and $E^{\star}$ other than they both connect $V_1$ and $V_2$.